# What are the low level protocols used by Micrologix PLCs?

Tags: c#, plc

I am building an application in C# which needs to talk to a Allen-Bradley Micrologix PLC. I know about the InGear driver to talk to it. I've used InGear in the past to talk to the other Allen-Bradley PLCs, and so I know that licensing with them can present problems to me.

What I want to know is: Are there any TCP or UDP based protocols for communicating directly with the Micrologix PLC? Obviously there must be something since InGear probably builds their protocol on some lower level protocol.

Comment: Did you looked at [Real time communications over UDP protocol](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275715/Real-time-communications-over-UDP-protocol-UDP-RT)

Comment: PLC vendors do not document their low-level interfaces.  Short from vendor-tie-in practices, they just don't like nor realistically *can* support their customers hacking their own.  This invariably gets extremely ugly when the deadline to startup the equipment is already passed and the interface just doesn't work or is not reliable enough.  Nobody ever got fired for using an InGear .NET wrapper, just make sure that licensing is not your problem.

Comment: I have no problem using Ingear's Net.Logix software, because that's what I have been using. I have a problem because Net.Logix won't connect to the Micrologix PLC that we bought. We have to use ABLink, but I don't know if we have the money to do that.

Additionally, I've made my own communication to different PLCs using a reasonably low level protocol. I've connected to an Omron PLC using FINS. I'm just looking to see if the Micrologix 1400 PLC has some similar support to connect to.

InGear isn't Allen Bradley, so how do they get this info?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I know how to make UDP and TCP communications to a device, but I don't know the message structure I am supposed to make to the MicroLogix 1400 device. That's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The Micrologix series PLC's use PCCC (aka CSP) protocol which is the DF1 protocol carried over TCP. The most lucid freely available code was written years ago by Ron Gage. Allen Bradley has a document available that details the origianl DF1 protocol quite well and in combination with Ron Gage's code it is pretty easy to figure out. Other than initial handshaking, it is a very simple request/response protocol. This is the same protocol that the PLC-5 series (from the 1980's) and the SLC series (from the 1990's) uses, but it is slowly being deprecated over time.

The second protocol that it supports is Ethernet/IP which uses a packet protocol called "CIP" which can be transported over either UDP or TCP but on initial contact you have to use TCP. The protocol standard is "open" and is published by the ODVA. This is also the same protocol that Omron brand PLC's among others use. For this communication you will want to use unconnected messaging mode (request/response). I've had great success using the "cpppo" protocol stack in Python but I have no idea what will work in .NET.

The third protocol that this PLC series uses is Modbus/TCP or Modbus (serial format), depending on the PLC. It can act as a master or slave. Modbus is the simplest protocol to use. Full documentation for the protocol itself is available for free on the modbus.org web site. I have worked with the older models but not the 1400 so I can't specifically state which flavors of Modbus it will support. Because this protocol is supported by essentially every PLC brand on the market, there are countless software libraries supporting it. Any reasonably competent programmer can usually write one in about a day worth of work from scratch because it is so simple.